# CSS transition not working when moving element

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition

I have a CSS element/ball which I am moving to new coordinates on click.

This works, however the transition I am applying does not seem to take affect.

The ball jumps to the new location. I want it to slowly animate/transition/move to the new coordinates.

What am I doing wrong?

```
.ball {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background-color: #FF5722;
    position: absolute;
    // d.style.transition = "all 1s ease-in";
    transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    // -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    // -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    // -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    // -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }

 handleClick = (e) => {
      console.log('ball clicked');
      var d = document.getElementById('ball');
      console.log('d', d);
      d.style.x =  12 + "px";
      d.style.top = 341 + "px";
      d.style.transition = "all 1s ease-in";
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: the transition should exist on the element before changing properties ... and that means before this code in the handler even runs

Comment: @JaromandaX - I did add it to the css class, but this did not work either..

Comment: If the transition is added last, then yes it would jump because the other values have already been changed. Usually though the transition is added to the css class so that it's there all the time.

Comment: `getElementById('ball')` .... would need `#ball` not `.ball` in your stylesheet

Comment: by the way, changing the transition like you are from 3 seconds in the stylesheet to 1 second inline, the transition probably will take 3 seconds not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are a few things that need to be corrected;

- The ball is styled by the `.ball` class in your CSS where as the ball element is being accessed via an id, which suggests a potential problem. Is the `ball` class being applied to the element with id `ball`?
- the `x` property on the style object should be replaced with the `left` property to ensure horizontal movement of the ball element
- ensure that the transition is assigned to the target elements prior to any CSS properties being modified

Here's an example demonstrating these corrections:

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {

  console.log('ball clicked');

  const ball = document.getElementById('ball');

  /* Setting random coordinates to demonstrate transition */
  ball.style.left = Number.parseInt(Math.random() * 200) + "px";
  ball.style.top = Number.parseInt(Math.random() * 200) + "px";
}

document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```css
#field {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Corrected to id selector with # rather than class selector 
   with . */
#ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FF5722;
  position: absolute;

  /* Assigning transition behavior which is applied during 
     property changes */
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Amazing - thank you so much guys!  I didn't realise I needed to set the default starting x and top coordinates. So this now works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a default value for `x` and `top` or you are trying to transition from nothing.

P.S. It seems your CSS is selecting elements with the CLASS `ball` instead of an element with the ID of `ball`. Use `#ball` instead of `.ball` in CSS. (credit to jaromanda-x)

```js
window.onclick = (e) => {
      console.log('ball clicked');
      var d = document.getElementById('ball');
      console.log('d', d);
      d.style.x =  12 + "px";
      d.style.top = 341 + "px";
      d.style.transition = "all 1s ease-in";
  }
```

```css
#ball {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background-color: #FF5722;
    position: absolute;
    // d.style.transition = "all 1s ease-in";
    transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    // -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    // -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    // -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    // -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    x:0; /* default value */
  top:0; /* default value */
  }
```

```html
<div id="ball">
```

Comment: you failed to mention OP's issue that the OP is using `.ball` instead of `#ball`